# Memory management in object oriented design using C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am working on a project which basically involves parsing and storing information about a large set of directories and files and gives me a summary of the number of files that were newly added (More like a 'File Sniffer').

The result of my program is that when I run it on say some 30 GB of data, I see the memory (working set) being allocated grow up to 700,000 K (memory leak).

In, my code, I am using quite a lot of object creation and destruction. The most used object is quite heavy.

Any suggestions as what could be done to reduce the memory usage. Please let me know if anything is unclear.

The main part of the code is something like this:

```
void analyzeHelper(std::string path){
    directory *dir=new directory();
    if(!dir->DirectoryExists(path))
        return;
    dir->SetCurrentDirectory(path);
    summary=new Summary();                        // Heavy class
    for(size_t i=0;i<dir->GetDirectories("*.*").size();i++)
        summary->addChild(dir->GetDirectories("*.*")[i]);
    for(size_t i=0;i<dir->GetFiles().size();i++)
        summary->addFile(Path<std::string>::toLower(dir->GetFiles()[i]));
    summary->setLocation(path);
    delete dir;
    compare(); //  here I run a comparision of the same directory with its previous version
    createMetadata(); // create an xml file to store the current version
    int size=summary->childSize();
    std::vector<std::string> _children=summary->getChildren();
    delete summary;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        FileSniffer *f=new FileSniffer(xmlroot);
        f->setRoot(dirRoot,path,remroot);
        f->analyzeHelper(_children[i]);
        delete f;
    }
```

}

**A related question: How bad is it to keep copying vectors? (As I am doing with '_children' in the code)**

Comment: Look up RAII and smart pointers, if you aren't using them already.

Comment: You can use tools like valgrind to help pinpoint memory leaks if you suspect them.

Comment: Could you maby provide the source code?.You must remember code can always be improved.Maby you have programmed it inefficiently which is a real possibilty in this case.Its really hard to judge at this stage what's wrong.C++ is a strongly typed out language and if you make the slightest of misteaks it will cost you.

Comment: Look through your code and find places where you do not free heap allocated memory. If you allocate memory inside object methods don't forget to free it in destructors.

Comment: Use a memory profiler like `valgrind`. Add Boehm's garbage collector. Rewrite in a more friendly language.

Comment: You seem to use `new` way too much. Do really need all those objects to be allocated on the heap?

Comment: I thought that would be the best idea, given lots of objects are being created. Otherwise, the objects would be in memory till the end of the function which is very bad for me

Comment: @Suchit: Not necessarily, read about scoping. You can easily do something like: `int main() { { int foo; } // foo is now freed }`. Heap allocation is expensive, and you must avoid it unless you really need it. Also, those in your last `for` loop will be freed at each iteration.

Comment: I just updated a part of my source code in the question

Comment: do you really need to copy those vectors? isn't enough to just hold a reference?

Comment: Note: `dir->DirectoryExists(path)` I find this code... dubious. You have a non-static member of `directory` that tells you if a directory exists. Why? Is `DirectoryExists` accessing some state from the `directory` instance? Why can't this be a free function or a static member? Then you could allocate the `directory` *after* you know you need to.

Comment: @NicolBolas Well, the directory instance is not useful other than to call that DirectoryExists function. An alternative to what I am doing could be Directory::DirectoryExists(path).

Comment: @Suchit: That's what I meant by a static member. That way, you move the allocation until after it and avoid creating something just to destroy it (or in your case, accidentally leaking it).

Comment: @lurscher: So for the summary->getChildren() function, do you mean I return the reference of the vector from getChildren and assign it to the one in this function? (Please correct me if I am wrong)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a memory leak if a directory does not exist:

```
directory *dir=new directory();
if(!dir->DirectoryExists(path))
    return;
```

`dir` must be deleted before returning (a smart pointer would simplify the management of `dir`) or just allocate `dir` on the stack:

```
directory dir;
if(!dir.DirectoryExists(path))
    return;
```

Comment: @hmjd: A stack-allocated object would simplify it even more. :)

Comment: No problem. Would need more detail on other parts of the code to comment on any other potential leaks.

Comment: You could also simply do `if (!directory().DirectoryExists(path))...`. Of course at this point, probably because off calling it statically.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are storing information about the files, not the files themselves it is more relevent of **how many** files those 30 GB of data consist. But in any case: It is unlikely that there are *that* many files, so you are probably right that there is a memory-leak.

There are tools that help you detect memory-leaks in your code; some of them cost a lot of money, some are free, all require some time to practice with them.

If you dont go the tool-route: To detect if there indeed is a leak you could just run your program on a smaller amount of data, say on 100000 files, then free all the objects you created, then repeat this in a loop and see if the memory goes up-and-down or steadily increases.

If you want us to help find the leak in your code, please post your code.

Comment: seems ok, but we cannot look into the sub-functions if they might allocate something